# Can We delete own parent coming from jquery in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to remove own block on clicking of cross... but it is not removing and nothing showing in error. Please help .....

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
            *{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                box-sizing:border-box;
            }

            .inputFileWrap{
                width:230px;
                position:relative;
                margin:10px 0;
            }

            .inputFileWrap i{
                position:absolute;
                right:0;
                top:0;
                cursor:pointer;
            }

            </style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
                var upload_element= '<div class="inputFileWrap"><input type="file" /><i class="fa fa-times crossIcon"></i></div>';
                $('#addUpload').click(function(e) {
                    $(this).before(upload_element);
                });

                $('.crossIcon').on('click', function(){
                    $(this).parent('.inputFileWrap').remove();
                });
            });
            </script>
<div class="inputFileWrap">
  <input type="file" />
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="addUpload">Add More</a>
```

Comment: use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Which error.please complete you question

Comment: @Pilot no error, nothing happen i guess

Comment: @A.Wolff ohk.. As usual Arun Sir wins the race

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/78SVK/1/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) since you are dealing with dynamic elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.crossIcon', function(){
    $(this).parent('.inputFileWrap').remove();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/78SVK/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Event-delegation to hook the events with elements which are created dynamically.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
                var upload_element= '<div class="inputFileWrap"><input type="file" /><i class="fa fa-times crossIcon">x</i></div>';
                $('#addUpload').click(function(e) {
                    $(this).before(upload_element);
                });

                $(document).on('click','.crossIcon', function(){
                    $(this).parent('.inputFileWrap').remove();
                });
            });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CBGsF/75/)